# Vue click two input one button

Tags: vue.js

I want to pick a new value when the button is clicked, but I can't

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-6 col-4" style="margin-top:5px;">
                        <p style="margin-bottom:0rem;" > Цена</p>
  <label>
                        <input  id="PriceRangeMin" type="number" :value='text' >
                            -
                        <input id="PriceRangeMax" placeholder="до" type="number" :value='text1'> 
  </label>
                        
                        <button id="PriceRangeMin" type="submit" style="margin-left:30px;"  @click='textcon()'>Применить</button>
                    </div>
```

My script

```
<script>



  
 

  export default {
    name: 'Applesmartphone',
    
    data () {
      return {
          
          text:[],
          text1:[]
          
        }
    },
    
      methods: {
        
        textcon(){
            
            console.log(text)
            console.log(text1)
        }




    }
    
  }
```

Hi, I want to pick a new value when the button is clicked, but I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind input to properties using v-model like :

```
 input  id="PriceRangeMin" type="number" v-model='text' >
```

then use `this` to access that properties inside the method :

```
    textcon(){
        
        console.log(this.text)
        console.log(this.text1)
    }
```